# How to get and its value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to show name with address of each entry.

```
var obj= ['{first: era,gold,jack}','{two:london,USA,India}']
$.each(obj,function(val,key){
alert(key)
//result era london, gold USA, jack India
})
```

Comment: You have an array containing two strings. I would suggest another data structure: `[['era', 'gold', 'jack'], ['london', 'USA', 'India']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array containing two strings. I would suggest another data structure:

```
var data = [['era', 'gold', 'jack'], ['london', 'USA', 'India']];

for (var i = 0, len = data[0].length; i < len; i++) {
  alert(data[0][i] + ': ' + data[1][i]);
}
```